# Container allocation code in YARN (Hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to tinker with the YARN container allocation code. By container allocation, I mean the decision to place the container on a specific machine in the cluster.

I want to write my own container allocation code. To begin with, I am running Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode with YARN. I am trying to locate the relevant points in the source code. So far, using print statements, I have been able to pinpoint the class `hadoop-source-code/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/impl/pb/client/ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java#allocate` where allocation takes place. However, I am unable to narrow it down further. Going further into this method, I have not been able to print anything.

To recap- I would like to locate the exact point in the Hadoop source code where I would need to write my own code to replace the existing container allocation mechnism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have not been able to print anything
```

At first, I thought logging is application specific but all information related to resource manager is under log file named `hadoop-{username}-resourcemanager-{username}.log` under `log` folder. Instead of print statement, I used `LOG.info` for debugging.

```
Location of allocation mechanism in hadoop source code
```

I am using FIFO scheduler and allocation mechanism is under method `FifoScheduler#assignContainersOnNode` which is called from `FifoScheduler#assignContainers` which is called from `FifoScheduler#nodeUpdate` method.

There is `FifoScheduler#handle` method [(more information here)](http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/07/22/schedulers-part-1/), which keeps on tracking of different events. `NODE_UPDATE` is among one of those which is triggered often and hence assignment of container on given node takes place.